# Importing data from Mathematica file

Tags: import

I have a array of Mathematica files which I am running one after another using NotebookOpen/SelectionMove/SelectionEvaluate functions successfully.

In this evaluation, the o/p of each file is a matrix, which is the input for next file. Say, the o/p X = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} in file1, I want to be "Imported" to file2 as Y.

I tried `Y = Import["Desktop/file1.nb", X]` in file2, but it comes back with message `$failed` !!

Will appreciate any suggestion on this.

Comment: How are you exporting `X`?

Comment: Export["Desktop/file2.nb", X]

Comment: Then why are you importing from file1.nb? What is `X` that is passed to `Import`?

Comment: Both of them not working. Neither individually nor together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have a hard time understanding your comments. This should help you with exporting and importing data between notebook files.

In `file1.nb`

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Export["~/output.mx", x];
```

In `file2.nb`

```
y = Import["~/output.mx"]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```